# How to set newer version of clang compiler?

Tags: compiler, clang

I installed cland++-15 compiler using:

```
sudo apt-get install clang++-15
```

after running `clang --version`
it shows

```
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

how can I update so the default will be clang++-15? checking the bin path, the clang++15 does exist.

Comment: `/usr/bin/clang++` is probably a symbolic link to the default `/usr/bin/clang++-10`

Answer (score -1):

```
$ sudo su
# cd /usr/lib/llvm-15/bin
# for f in *; do rm -f /usr/bin/$f; \
    ln -s ../lib/llvm-15/bin/$f /usr/bin/$f; done
# exit
$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 15.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

When LLVM 16 comes out do the exact same thing just replace 15 with 16 in the above etc.